# Linq "group by" values in a Dictionary property with a list of keys

Tags: linq, dictionary, group-by

I have the following list of objects

```
List<Obj> source = new List<Obj>();
source.Add(new Obj() { Name = "o1", Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "attA", "1" }, { "attB", "1" }, { "attC", "1" } } });
source.Add(new Obj() { Name = "o2", Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "attA", "1" }, { "attB", "2" }, { "attC", "1" } } });
source.Add(new Obj() { Name = "o3", Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "attA", "1" }, { "attB", "3" }, { "attC", "2" } } });
source.Add(new Obj() { Name = "o4", Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "attA", "1" }, { "attB", "4" }, { "attC", "2" } } });
source.Add(new Obj() { Name = "o5", Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "attA", "2" }, { "attB", "5" }, { "attC", "3" } } });
source.Add(new Obj() { Name = "o6", Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "attA", "2" }, { "attB", "6" }, { "attC", "3" } } });
source.Add(new Obj() { Name = "o7", Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "attA", "2" }, { "attB", "7" }, { "attC", "4" } } });
source.Add(new Obj() { Name = "o8", Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "attA", "2" }, { "attB", "8" }, { "attC", "4" } } });
```

so i need to group it by the values of a specific attribute(s), furthermore the names of these  attributes are kept in a separate list, like:

```
List<string> groupBy = new List<string>() { "attA", "attC" };
```

i tried using

```
var groups =
       from s in source
       group s by s.Attributes["attA"];
```

this works fine, returning 2 groups:

- "1" - "o1 o2 o3 o4"
- "2" - "o5 o6 o7 o8"

but what actually I need to do is to group by "attA" and "attC" (or whatever is in the groupBy variable) and get the following four groups:

- "1_1" - "o1 o2"
- "1_2" - "o3 o4"
- "2_3" - "o4 o5"
- "2_4" - "o7 o8"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from c in source
group c by String.Join("_",groupBy.Select(gr=>c.Attributes[gr]).ToArray()) into gr
select new 
{
   AttrValues = gr.Key,
   //Values = gr.Key.Split('_'),
   Names = gr.Select(c=>c.Name).ToList()
};
```

The group key is the concatenated projection of the dictionary values obtained from **groupBy** list of keys.

Comment: Works like a dream. If you ever visit Sofia, know you got a free beer from me.

Comment: @AdrianIftode, what is the equivalent of your query using extension methods? like `var query=source.GroupBy(....`

Answer (score 0):

You can group by multiple properties:

```
var groups = from s in source
             group s by new 
             { 
                AttributeA = s.Attributes["attA"], 
                AttributeC = s.Attributes["attC"] 
             };

//shows 4 groups
foreach (var group in groups)
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key.AttributeA + "_" + group.Key.AttributeC);
```

Comment: yes, works fine, but i need to group by the attributes, contained in the 'List<string> groupBy' varialbe